# 4.0 (8A293) can we restore into iOS 4

Tags: iphone, xcode

hey,
I want to test my app with xcode 3.2 on iOS 4
the error I am getting is " provision  file is missing" although I do have the provision file installed in the organizer

I am getting this when I open the orginizer 
OS Installed on your Iphone is 
4.2.1 (8C148)

Xcode Supported iPhone OS Versions
4.0 (8A293)
3.2
3.1.3
3.1.2
3.1.1
3.1
3.0.1
3.0
either restore youur iOS or update it with newer version

how to solve this issue? how can I restore earlier version ie 4.0 (8A293) on my iOS 
I suspect it might be what causing the error 
anybody is facing the same problem? or can help me solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your build settings are not such that you can build on your device since its version is newer than your settings. You should check your Base SDK settings for your target and make sure it is set to something the same or newer than what is on your device. If you are using an older version of XCode which doesn't support your device version, then you'll either have to upgrade XCode or downgrade your device.

Comment: how can I downgrade my device ? to 4.0 (8A293) instead of 4.2.1 (8C148)?                                                            as I am guessing my code should change if i upgrade my XCode